# Create a Loop to Iterate All Combinations of Successes/Failures of Events

Tags: vba

I'm writing a code that calculates the probability given a certain amount of successes. I'm having trouble writing a for loop such that I can categorize some events as failures and some as successes. I was able to do it for Case Is = 1, but I'm not thinking of any clever way to iterate the other cases in a way that would go through all combinations of successes and failures given an amount of successes that the user inputs.

I have made an attempt for Case=2, but can't think of a way to record the failures. In Case=1, I worked around it by using modulus.

```
Function CustomBinomial(MoveType, SuccessAmount) As Double

'Variables to record which events succeed and fail
    Dim FirstEvent As Double
    Dim SecondEvent As Double
    Dim ThirdEvent As Double
    Dim FourthEvent As Double
    Dim FifthEvent As Double
    Dim SixthEvent As Double

'Rows the probability values are in
ProbSuccessArray = Array(15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35)
    
    Select Case SuccessAmount
        Case Is = 0
            'Record 0 events as successful
        Case Is = 1
            For i = 0 To 5
                'Record 1 event as successful
                FirstEvent = ProbSuccessArray(i)
                
                'Record 5 events as failures
                SecondEvent = ProbSuccessArray((i + 1) Mod 6)
                ThirdEvent = ProbSuccessArray((i + 2) Mod 6)
                FourthEvent = ProbSuccessArray((i + 3) Mod 6)
                FifthEvent = ProbSuccessArray((i + 4) Mod 6)
                SixthEvent = ProbSuccessArray((i + 5) Mod 6)
                
                CustomBinomial = CustomBinomial + Cells(FirstEvent, 3).Value * (1 - Cells(SecondEvent, 3).Value) _
                                * (1 - Cells(ThirdEvent, 3).Value) * (1 - Cells(FourthEvent, 3).Value) _
                                * (1 - Cells(FifthEvent, 3).Value) * (1 - Cells(SixthEvent, 3).Value)
                
            Next i
        Case Is = 2
            For i = 0 To 5
                For j = 1 To 5
                    'Record 2 events as successful
                    If i = j Then GoTo Continue
                    FirstEvent = ProbSuccessArray(i)
                    SecondEvent = ProbSuccessArray(j)
                    
                    'Record 4 events as failures
                    'code here
                    
                    'CustomBinomial = CustomBinomial + Successes * Failures
Continue:
                Next j
            Next i
        Case Is = 3
        'Record 3 events as successful
        Case Is = 4
        'Record 4 events as successful
        Case Is = 5
        'Record 5 events as successful
        Case Is = 6
        'Record 6 events as successful
                
                    
    End Select
```

Comment: Your current question is gobbledegook.  Can you please clarify what you mean by an event (Event is a word with a very specific meaning in VBA), what is a success and what is a failure etc

Comment: We have no idea what the logic is for each case. Presumably, if math can solve it for one case it may well solve it for all cases.